# Correct usage of return if in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, syntax

So in Kotlin you can write the below function in two ways:

```
fun getProduct(id: Int): Product? {
    if (id < 1 ) return null
    return productProvider.getProduct(id) /// Assuming getProduct NEVER fails
}
```

Or as below:

```
fun getProduct(id: Int) = if (id > 0 ){
   productProvider.getProduct(id) /// Assuming getProduct NEVER fails
}else {
    null
}
```

I am being suggested to always use the latter, as is the proper way.
Can someone point me in the right direction on this? Why is the second syntax better?

I can guess that performance wise they are exactly the same and ( IMO ) I do not find the second one more readable at all.

Comment: To the down- and close-voters, this isn't a question requesting opinions. It's asking if there is more to it than just opinion, so it is a valid question. A new Kotlin user might not know if there could be a performance impact, or whether there is an official syntax convention that is being violated by the first block of code.

Comment: I disagree. The question is "Why is the second syntax better?" Opinion.

Comment: @matt, I guess I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt due to possible English language unfamiliarity. Their last sentence shows they are unsure if performance is a factor.

Comment: @matt I am asking specifically about PERFORMANCE and Kotlin functionality itself. In no way I am asking anyone "Which do you like more?" because I literally do not care.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios That may be what you _mean_ but it is no way what the question actually _says_. Feel free to edit the question to make it more like what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not more correct or better-performing. It is a style choice.

You do have the option of including the return type to make the second one more readable:

```
fun getProduct(id: Int): Product? = if (id > 0 ) {
    productProvider.getProduct(id)
} else {
    null
}
```

A when expression could also help here.

Comment: In terms of readability I often use _when { ... }_.

Comment: "It is not more correct or better-performing. It is a style choice" Then this is a matter of opinion and you should vote to close and not answer.

Comment: @matt, I shouldn't have inserted my opinion at the end of my answer, but the question is valid. "Is this syntax difference affecting performance or breaking an official syntax convention?" is not an opinion-based question. The answer is "no", which is not an opinion.